Aquiring Azure B2C token programmatically results in unresolved protocol handler error
We're investigating moving to Azure B2C and as part of a PoC we've successfully set up a user journey with interactive sign-in and enriched claims via an API call. However, we also need the ability to have a non-interactive sign-in. We've followed this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/scenario-desktop-acquire-token-username-password
However, this results in a 500: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalServiceException: AADB2C: An exception has occurred.
Application Insights has more detail:
Exception Message:An attempt was made to resolve a protocol handler for unsupported protocol "Proprietary" in technical profile with id "SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" in policy with id "B2C_1A_signup_signin" for tenant with id "<tentant>.onmicrosoft.com"., Exception Type:PolicyException, CorrelationID:<correlation guid>

There seems to only be one other instance of someone running into this issue and asking about it, but without any answers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/524941/retrieve-azure-b2c-bearer-token
We've tried the following so far

Skipping the SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email technical profile and using the login-NonInteractive profile directly. This actually appears to be an invalid config that is validated against when uploading the policies, but it's possible to get around the validation by uploading the policy first and then updating the extensions. When this is in place, calls to the API fail with AADB2C90225: The username or password provided in the request are invalid. which appears to be an error message that shows up when the configuration is invalid. We've double checked the resource and clientId values mentioned here (and they are working with the interactive sign-in): https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/issues/173
That error message did lead us to another question from someone trying to do the same thing. They had a different issue but we tried copying their example policies and ran into the same error message about the unresolved protocol handler. This was the example we duplicated: B2C custom policy login - "The username or password provided in the request are invalid"
We've also tried various other tutorials without much luck. They usually involve the interactive sign-in at some stage of the process. Example: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/entra/identity-platform/howto-call-a-web-api-with-curl

What we want to do
We want to have our own endpoint that accepts username, password, grant_type, etc. and then be able to programmatically call Azure B2C with the given details in order to retrieve a bearer token containing the relevant claims. The guide linked in the opening paragraph seems to be what we need, but we cannot get it to work.

The link you referenced points to a ROPC flow.
You can do this in B2C, but it's not secure.
An alternative would be to use B2C's "successor" Entra External ID for Customers.
This does have a native authentication flow.

Thanks! Entra External ID native authentication is what we needed. For anyone else looking, it's not limited to native/desktop apps either, it supports web apps too.
